# Hiding a modal window without using close button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image gallery. clicking on any image opens a modal window with the clicked in image.
I want to hide the modal window. i know how to do it by putting a close button. But i don't want to add any close button. what i am trying to do is whenever a user click anywhere other then following div `gallery-image` `gallery-control-previous` `gallery-control-next` the modal window should get hidden.

can anyone suggest me how to achieve this.

Here is my  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSc8E/16/)

Comment: Somebody thinks *This question does not appear to be about programming* ??? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSc8E/20)..

add this to end of your jquery code.

```
$(".gallery-overlay").click(function(e) {
    if($(e.target).hasClass("gallery-image") || $(e.target).hasClass("gallery-control-next") || $(e.target) .hasClass("gallery-control-previous")){/**/}
    else {$(".gallery-overlay").fadeOut("2000");
    }
});
```

e.target gives the actual clicked area, within `.gallery-overlay`. `$(this)` doesn't work.
You can slow down the rate of fading of modal window by increasing time. Here it is 2000, i.e.2 seconds.

Comment: @OptimusPrime ty i sometimes like to appreciated ;)

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/TSc8E/34/)</kbd>

Hide on clicking other than `navigation keys`

```
$('.gallery-overlay').click(function(event){
    if($(event.target).hasClass('gallery-control') ==false){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Hide on clicking other than `image` and `navigation keys`

```
$('.gallery-overlay').click(function(event){
    if($(event.target).hasClass('gallery-control') ==false && $(event.target).hasClass('gallery-image') == false){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

you can use `fadeout('slow')` instead of hide for giving good effects

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following to your code:

```
$('.gallery-overlay').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
});

$('.gallery-image').click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

You will also need to add `return false` at the end of your `click` handlers for `.gallery-control-previous`, `.gallery-control-next` and `.gallery-image` so that the event doesn't propagate to `.gallery-overlay`.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSc8E/28/).

Comment: i checked your fiddle. the modal window is disappearing after clicking on those div which i mentioned not to disappear

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a click event to `fadeOut()` the `.gallery-overlay` onclick.

[**View the JSFiddle for an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/TSc8E/30/)

Then for your `.gallery-captionbox` and `.gallery-image`, add a `click` event and `return false` on them.

```
// Hide the gallery on click
$('.gallery-overlay').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});

// Return false on click of the caption box or the image itself
$('.gallery-captionbox, .gallery-image').click(function(){
    return false;
});

// All your other code below
```

[**View the JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TSc8E/30/)

Answer (score -1):

Try,

```
   $(document).click(function(e) {

       if( e.target.id != 'yourDivId') {
           $("#yourDivId").hide();
       }
   });
```